# how get user roles's slug in rails for the current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise, roles

I have a roles based authentication with devise gem; all users can has many roles and
how can i retrieve just user role slug for the current_user?

now in my User.rb model i have created a method called get_role

User.rb

```
def get_role
  roles.each { |role| role.slug.downcase }
end
```

i call this method in a view like that

```
current_user.get_role
```

and it returns this:

```
[#<Role id: 3, name: "Seller", created_at: "2013-01-10 21:04:46", updated_at: "2013-01-10 21:04:46", slug: "Venditore">]
```

why if a call an each block in that method?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map` ([doc for map method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-map)) instead of `each` ([doc for each method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-each)):

```
def get_role
  roles.map { |role| role.slug.downcase }
end
```

When you iterate a collection with `each` the returned value will be the collection itself. `each` iterator is for doing something with each element. And it's property allow you to write chains of `each` method calls:

```
workers.each{ |w| w.take_a_break }.each{ |w| w.just_joke_go_to_work }
```

Not very smart example, because we may do just:

```
workers.each{ |w| w.take_a_break; w.just_joke_go_to_work }
```

But just as an example.

Comment: ok thanks, i'll study the difference between the two methods. but why it retrieve `["venditore"]` instead `venditore`?

Comment: ok it returns always an array, but maybe the user role will be always one although is an `has_many` association so i want to return the single role. so i change the method name with `role_names` but i don't understand why, is only because is a conventional way to named the method?

Comment: yes you're right but maybe the users may have more roles in future, but i want to print out just the first role anyway